# Unable to sign into google with selenium automation because of "This browser or app may not be secure."

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to login to google with selenium and I keep getting the error that "This browser or app may not be secure."

The function I use to log in is:

```
async function loginToChrome(driver, username, password) {
  await driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin");
  await driver.sleep(1000);
  let email_phone = await driver.findElement(
    By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")
  );
  await email_phone.sendKeys(username);
  await driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
  await driver.sleep(1000);

  let passEl = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"));
  await passEl.sendKeys(password);
  await driver.findElement(By.id("passwordNext")).click();
  await driver.sleep(1000);
}
```

It is the same problem as
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59433453/unable-to-log-into-google-account-in-selenium-chrome-driver
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276975/couldnt-sign-you-in-this-browser-or-app-may-be-insecure-python-selenium-chrome

I have tried using both the chrome and firefox web drivers and both don't work.
I have also tried doing `.excludeSwitches(['enable-automation'])` which also didn't help.

This made me think that maybe the sign-in page could detect that I was running in an automated environment.
I tried this solution that would hide that the app is running in a web driver: [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver)

I have also looked into the `User-Agent` to see if that was the problem but what I have found is that it is identical to my regular chrome one.

All of this has not worked which makes leaves me stuck. I have seen solutions that say to use an already created user profile from your normal installation of chrome, but this wouldn't work for my use case.

Has anyone found the solution to this? I have been searching for hours and have come up empty-handed.

**EDIT:**
It seems like this has been getting a lot of attention recently. I found a solution that allowed me to continue to use an automated client without having too many problems. Switching to Puppeteer.
Look into these packages:

```
    "puppeteer",
    "puppeteer-extra",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth"
```

EDIT 2:
I have seen this get a lot of attention recently. I found the code that I ended up using to login. I used puppeteer instead of selenium to do this

```
async function login(
  page: Page,
  username: string,
  password: string,
  backup: string
) {
  await page.goto("https://accounts.google.com/");

  await page.waitForNavigation();

  await page.waitForSelector('input[type="email"]');
  await page.click('input[type="email"]');

  await page.waitForNavigation();

  //TODO : change to your email
  await page.type('input[type="email"]', username);
  await page.waitForSelector("#identifierNext");
  await page.click("#identifierNext");

  await page.waitFor(1000);

  await page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]');
  await page.click('input[type="password"]');
  await page.waitFor(500);
  //TODO : change to your password
  await page.type('input[type="password"]', password);

  await page.waitForSelector("#passwordNext");
  await page.click("#passwordNext");
  await page.waitForNavigation();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The followings work me as well:
1. try to login stackoverflow with your google account
2. once login, go to the email

here is solution

```
     WebDriver driver;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
     GeneralClass te =  new GeneralClass ();

    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/identifier?client_id=717762328687-iludtf96g1hinl76e4lc1b9a82g457nn."
            + "apps.googleusercontent.com&as=JS6BM8cjL-8j9votansdkw&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fstackauth"
            + ".com&approval_state=!ChRoYWVvLUlNMk5hSXJWUGlaSVl2WBIfc3lSa0lueENpb29lSU5vbEVpbVNxcUZGaGNkSEJoYw%E2%88%99AJDr988AAAAAXlBKc7PzEomxSzgNqd4wLptVlf0Ny3Qx&oauthgdpr=1&xsrfsig=ChkAeAh8T8JNDxCf2Zah5fb_rQ55OMiF8KmMEg5hcHByb3ZhbF9zdGF0ZRILZGVzdGluYXRpb24SBXNvYWN1Eg9vYXV0aHJpc2t5c2NvcGU&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow");
     te.waitingForElementSendingKey(driver, By.id("identifierId"), "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com");
     te.waitingForElementForClickOnly(driver, By.id("identifierNext"));
     te.waitingForElementSendingKey(driver,By.name("password"), "PASSSWORD");
     te.waitingForElementForClickOnly(driver, By.id("passwordNext"));
     Thread.sleep(1500);
     driver.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox");
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you write it for python?

Answer (score 5):

I just tried something out that worked for me after several hours of trial and error.

Adding `args: ['--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir', '--allow-running-insecure-content' ]` to my config resolved the issue.

I realized later that this was not what helped me out as I tried with a different email and it didn't work. After some observations, I figured something else out and this has been tried and tested.

**Using automation**:

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/login
Select Log in with Google Strategy
Enter Google username and password
Login to Stackoverflow
Go to https://gmail.com (or whatever Google app you want to access)

After doing this consistently for like a whole day (about 24 hours), try automating your login directly to gmail (or whatever Google app you want to access) directly... I've had at least two other people do this with success.
PS - You might want to continue with the stackoverflow login until you at least get a captcha request as we all went through that phase as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Those config solved my issue! My issue is that in my login screen, there's a Login button via Gmail, everything works properly with Normal Chrome, but cannot login with Headless chrome. Adding `--disable-web-security` and `--allow-running-insecure-content` solved the issue!

Comment: @LinhNhatNguyen although those were what I tried first to resolve my issue and it didn't actually resolve it (something else did which was the update I provided using automation), I'm glad leaving that there helped you with yours.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround that worked for me is creating a google account in the chrome instance started by the webdriver. Using this newly created account works for me, but I cannot tell what is exactly the difference between it and other google accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

I am using Puppeteer, but I'd bet it's the same for any automated scripts.

You must have a userDataDirectory so that the browser can use the same storage information.

You must initially run the script with `headless: false` so that you can get a browser to open.  If you try to sign in on the current tab (the tab that was navigated automatically), then you will get that error on every sign-in attempt.

The trick (for me) was to open a new tab, navigate manually, try again.

Next time you run the script, you do not need to login.

Comment: Sorry, this trick doesn't work anymore for about a week now (see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773283/google-login-fails-with-http-error-400-saying-sorry-something-went-wrong-there/63773378). Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Today I experienced the same issue. The solution in this issue worked for me:

- Disable Two Factor Authentication for this Google account and execute your @Test.

My environment details:

- net6.0; c#
- Selenium.Support (nuget) Version="4.10.0"

The followings didn't work for me:

1. try to login stackoverflow with your Google account.
2. once login, go to the email

The following answer also didn't solve the issue:

- Adding args: `'--disable-web-security', '--allow-running-insecure-content'`

Answer (score -1):

Try using undetected_chromedriver library :

```
!pip install undetected_chromedriver

import undetected_chromedriver as uc

driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe') #change for your path

driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin') 
#continue work code here...
```

It worked pretty well for me

Answer (score -3):

This error message...

```
This browser or app may not be secure.
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.
```

...implies that the *WebDriver* was unable to authenticate the **Browsing Context** i.e. **Browser** session.

---

### Potential reasons and solution

There can be diverse reason behind this error as follows:

- @Raphael Schaad in the article ["This browser or app may not be secure" error when trying to sign in with Google on desktop apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/22873505?hl=en) mentioned that, if an user can log into the same app just fine with other Google accounts, then the problem must lie with the particular account. The possible reason, it is the only account where user is using **Two Factor Authentification**.
- Another pottential reason can be usage of [Less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255). If an app or site doesn’t meet [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome)'s [security standards](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255#more-secure-apps-how), Google may block anyone who’s trying to sign in to your account from it. Less secure apps can make it easier for hackers to get in to your account, so blocking sign-ins from these apps helps keep your account safe.

### Solution

In these cases the respective solution would be to:

- Disable *Two Factor Authentification* for this Google account and execute your *@Test*.
- [Allow less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Sign in to gmail account fails (selenium automation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534028/sign-in-to-gmail-account-fails-selenium-automation/59569816#59569816)

---

### tl; dr

A couple of relevent documentation:

- [Sign in with a supported browser](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en)

Comment: This doesnt work. I am using selenium ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 and the account doesn't have Two Factor Authentification and Allow less secure apps are turned on.

Comment: None of the two above suggestions are working

Comment: None of the solution is working. Have you tested before posting?

Comment: Disabling two factor auth and allow less secure app on test account works for me. Thanks.