# WebDriverException: Service ...\firefox.exe unexpectedly exited error using GeckDriver Firefox through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, mechanize, geckodriver

`selenium` uses "fake" browsers that Google sign-in rejects ("This browser app is not secure"), `mechanize` lacks a GUI, `webbrowser` can't click. Is there any package that can open the "usual" browser that won't be rejected by third-party services?

---

For reference, here's what happens if I try to supply the "usual" Firefox executable path to selenium:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
exepath = r"C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=exepath)
```

The browser does open, but selenium fails to connect:

```py
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 98, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
% (self.path, return_code)

WebDriverException: Service C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe unexpectedly exited. 
Status code was: 0
```

I searched for this exact error - all solutions point back to using the "WebDriver" (i.e. "fake browser"). Tried also with Chrome - same deal, except it first waits 30 secs before throwing the error.

---

**Note**: `geckodriver` and `ChromeDriver` are both WebDrivers - the "fake" browsers.

**Note 2**: this is the message I'm getting: (and link to [Learn more](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7675428?hl=en))

[image]

This is how WebDriver's URL appears:

[image]

Comment: There's also an ongoing discussion about this here: https://gist.github.com/ikegami-yukino/51b247080976cb41fe93 (Adding for reference). Seems like others are facing the same issue

Comment: You can download geckdriver exe and give the path of it in executable path

Comment: @nopassport1 Right, I did notice a few "dev-stage" efforts, but I need a solution sooner - wish them luck regardless

Comment: @Murthi I address this exact suggestion at the bottom of my post

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't have "fake" browsers, it uses browsers installed on the machine. The `executable_path` is for `geckodriver`/`ChromeDriver`, not `firefox.exe`.

```
exepath = "path_to\geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=exepath)
```

Comment: The browser is detected as "automated test software" by Google, and is rejected as insecure - so "fake" or not, it is a problem.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The insecure is on the url, not the browser. And you can remove the warning by adding `FirefoxOptions()` with option `useAutomationExtension`.

Comment: As noted in my post, when I try to sign in, I am notified "This browser app is not secure" - and I _cannot sign in_; not just a warning.

Comment: Also can't test your suggestion as I'm unsure how it's done exactly; `opts=FirefoxOptions();` `opts.add_argument('useAutomationExtension');` `Firefox(options=opts)` yields error: `WebDriverException: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect. If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.`

Answer (score 0):

`exepath` need to path to geckodriver not firefox.

```
exepath = r"path\geckodriver.exe"


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=exepath)
```

Comment: This is the WebDriver I noted to be problematic in my question.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of more details about your usecase and why you felt [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) uses **fake** browsers, would have helped us to construct a more canonical answer.

However to start with, this is the reason [Why Firefox requires GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver/43661697#43661697) and *GeckoDriver* scoops up a brand new **moz:profile** on the fly during each execution.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Is it Firefox or Geckodriver, which creates “rust_mozprofile” directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46088442/is-it-firefox-or-geckodriver-which-creates-rust-mozprofile-directory/46089240#46089240)

---

### Error you are facing

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: Service C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe unexpectedly exited. 
Status code was: 0
```

...implies that the *GeckoDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

---

### executable_path

[executable_path](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) is the parameter through which users can pass the **absolute path** of the *GeckoDriver* binary overriding the **system path** of *GeckoDriver* binary to be used for Firefox 47.0.1 and greater.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [What is the executable_path in Google Colaboratory for geckodriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528718/what-is-the-executable-path-in-google-colaboratory-for-geckodriver/57553986#57553986)

---

### This usecase

To supply the *usual* *Firefox* executable/binary path you need to use the `binary` property through an instance of `FirefoxOptions()` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

binary = r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = binary
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('http://google.com/')
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to open Firefox Developer Edition through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754686/how-to-open-firefox-developer-edition-through-selenium/54762442#54762442)

---

### This browser app is not secure

There can be diverse reason bhind this error as follows:

- @Raphael Schaad in the article ["This browser or app may not be secure" error when trying to sign in with Google on desktop apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/thread/22873505?hl=en) mentioned that, if an user can log into the same app just fine with other Google accounts, then the problem must lie with the particular account. The possible reason, it is the only account where user is using **Two Factor Authentification**.
- Another pottential reason can be usage of [Less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255). If an app or site doesn’t meet [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome)'s [security standards](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255#more-secure-apps-how), Google may block anyone who’s trying to sign in to your account from it. Less secure apps can make it easier for hackers to get in to your account, so blocking sign-ins from these apps helps keep your account safe.

### Solution

In these cases the respective solution would be to:

- Disable **Two Factor Authentification** for this Google account and execute your *@Test*.
- [Allow less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Unable to sign into google with selenium automation because of “This browser or app may not be secure.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59514049/unable-to-sign-into-google-with-selenium-automation-because-of-this-browser-or/59515341#59515341)
- [Sign in to gmail account fails (selenium automation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59534028/sign-in-to-gmail-account-fails-selenium-automation/59569816#59569816)

Comment: I'll read your sources - in the meantime, your suggestion didn't work; as far as what I see, nothing changed. I've updated my question. -- Regarding "fake" - simply per Google calling it "insecure" and the browser touting it "automated test software", so basically an incomplete, sandbox-like alternative rather than the "real thing" - but yes, I could be wrong.

Comment: Couldn't fully interpret your links, but from what I understood, GeckoDriver is an "interface" between user input commands and the browser itself. Then ideally, Google shouldn't be complaining; whatever the case, something about Selenium's spawned browser is being seen differently on the receiving end.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Checkout the updated answer and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The `FirefoxBinary` approach didn't work; I don't use TwoFactorAuthentication; all of my accounts fail. As for "allow less secure apps" - that's a rather unreasonable expectation on behalf of `selenium`; why should users expose themselves to security risks? I understand there may 'overreactions', but I don't know what the exact risks are, so I rather not tread that territory.