# python selenium gmail automaton

Tags: python, selenium, automation

It seemed I couldn't automate gmail login. my code was right but once selenium typing the username and clicking next, it wouldn't let me type in the password.

Below was what showed in the password page:
**Couldn’t sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.**

Is there a way to solve this?

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")

#driver.maximize_window()

#driver.find_element_by_class_name("whsOnd").send_keys("email address")
#driver.find_element_by_class_name("VfPpkd-RLmnJb").click()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59514049/unable-to-sign-into-google-with-selenium-automation-because-of-this-browser-or

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to sign into google with selenium automation because of "This browser or app may not be secure."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59514049/unable-to-sign-into-google-with-selenium-automation-because-of-this-browser-or)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“This browser or app may not be secure” error while attempting to login in to Gmail account using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515561/this-browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-error-while-attempting-to-login-in-to-gm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/ which is an undetected driver. This should work.

Comment: can you specify how to use it? do I need to use this one instead of the chrome driver I already downloaded.

Comment: You can just put                                                                                                                import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
with driver: