# how to fix This browser or app may not be secure. error when using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class ClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeDriver drive = new ChromeDriver();
        drive.get("https://accounts.google.com");
        drive.manage().window().maximize();
        drive.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("********@gmail.com");
        drive.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'identifierNext\']/div/button/span")).click();
        drive.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("*******");

        drive.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='passwordNext']/div/button/span")).click();

    }

}
```

When I trying to login to Gmail using selenium I getting this error
"This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in."
I have even on less security and off 2 step verification too still the same issue, can you please help me with this

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515561/this-browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-error-while-attempting-to-login-in-to-gm/62195934 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59514049/unable-to-sign-into-google-with-selenium-automation-because-of-this-browser-or

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“This browser or app may not be secure” error while attempting to login in to Gmail account using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515561/this-browser-or-app-may-not-be-secure-error-while-attempting-to-login-in-to-gm)

Answer (score 0):

The user agent has to be set in your driver. Add a valid user agent to a `ChromeOptions` instance and pass that to the `ChromeDriver` constructor.

For example:

```java
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36");
ChromeDriver drive = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: it is `options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)` if using python, but this doesnt fix error "This browser or app may not be secure." for me