# Error with Google Login using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, gmail

When I am trying to login to Google using Selenium, it gives an error that This browser or app may not be secure. I have tried undetected chrome-driver and with firefox as well but no luck.
It seems that all old solutions are not working now.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Note:I can not do it with already opened browser

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68566449/21153726 and here is your solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/68568262/21153726

Comment: Here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78148407/3806036